# How to set sub panels have the same width as their container with GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I have a main JPanel that I would want to use as a container for more panels. I would like the child panels to have the same width as its parent and I tried using GridBagLayout to achieve it:

```
private JPanel createPanels() {
    JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.add(new JLabel("Test"));
    p1.add(new JButton("+"));

    content.add(p1, gbc);

    return content;
}
```

With this piece of code, I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the panel that just got created doesn't fit the width of its container (green panel). I thought `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;` and `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` lines would be in charge of doing that, but apparently they did not.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your code and created the following GUI.

[image: Example]

In your code, you created a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` and placed it inside a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout`.  The `FlowLayout` `JPanel` is considered one Swing component, so it won't adjust to the container size.

I added a `main` method and a `JFrame` to your code to show the difference.

Here's the complete runnable code that I think you want.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutTest2 implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutTest2());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createPanels(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPanels() {
        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        content.add(new JLabel("Test"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        content.add(new JButton("+"), gbc);

        return content;
    }

}
```